# Android Bug, RecyclerView opens up full keyboard after EditText's keypad's done is cliked

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-recyclerview

My EditText for some reason is acting weird.

My edittext is contained inside a scrolling RecyclerView. When I click on edit text, keypad shows up just fine, and when "Done" from the keypad is clicked, the keypad closes BUT the full keyboard shows up. Any thought what the issue is or a way to prevent the FULL keyboard to show up? Thanks.

EDIT:: I manage to solve the Done problem but when keypad is open and i scroll down the recyclerview, the keypad closes and the full keyboard shows up. might be a problem with focus like mentioned in one of the answers below.

```
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) v.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
                    invAdded.clearFocus();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
```

ORIGINAL ::

```
  <EditText
        android:id="@+id/di_inventory_added"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        />
```

and the container layout

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_below="@id/include"
    android:id="@+id/daily_inventory_recycle_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

and also the actioneditlistener

```
  invAdded.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {

                    invAdded.clearFocus();
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by full keyboard?

Comment: full alphabetic and number keyboard, not keypad

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you you are not returning right boolean value in `onEditorAction` callback method.

if you want to hide keyboard you have to tell system that you have consumed `done` button event by returning `true` in `onEditorAction` method.

```
invAdded.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {

                invAdded.clearFocus();
            }
            return true; // return true(event consumed)
        }
    });
```

i haven't tested it. It is just a guess you can try it.
Hope it would help.

Comment: testing it now, will let you know after build, thanks

Comment: now i understood you problem. from you edited question.

Comment: problem is when you press done button focus is moved to another edittext that requires full keyboard.

Comment: the other edit texts have been set to number only though, still probable but I'm not entirely sure. i'll check again. but  i managed to solve it by calling  hideSoftInputFromWindow from inputmethodmanager. but full keyboard still SHOWS UP when the keypad is open and I scroll down the recyclerview.

Comment: I'm trying now to call the same function (hidesoftinputformwindow) from the onbindviewholder.

Comment: @JackSmother Do you find any solution for this.I also have the same issue..